# Is there a way to call a $\text{min} > \text{percentage} > \text{max}$ modelisation?

Tags: functions

Let's say I have an initial value $1000$.

From that amount I take $10\%$: $100$. My final value has to be between $200$ and $500$. Hence my final result is $200$.

Is there a correct *semantic* way of calling that $\text{min} < \text{percentage of initial value} < \text{max}$ type of function?

Comment: Do you mean something like *constrained*?

Comment: *constrained* sounds good. I was wondering if there was a term specific to this exact type of function with two boundaries and a percentage in the middle.